# How to populate data in the subtraction of 2 value sets in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a collection of students in table "AllStudents", another table "Points" to link their studentId with Points. Now I want to populate table "Points" all other studentIDs that doesn't have points yet with value "NEWVALUE"

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO `myDB`.`Points` (`point`, `student_id`) VALUES ('NEWVALUE', '(select `studentId` from `myDB`.`AllStudents` where `studentId` is not in (select `studentId` from `myDB`.`Points`) )');
```

but it is not working. 
I guess my mistake is in passing the values and lacking of a loop ? 
How could I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following using a [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) and [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
INSERT INTO `myDB`.`Points` (`point`, `student_id`)
  SELECT 'NEWVALUE', `studentId` 
  FROM `myDB`.`AllStudents` 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `myDB`.`Points` 
    WHERE `myDB`.`Points`.`student_id` = `myDB`.`AllStudents`.`studentId`
  )
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c07fc8ef8f005020ea193f0a88fc889)

Comment: my NEWVALUE is not existing in either AllStudents and Points tables. This query I run fails

Comment: `NEWVALUE` is not a column here, it is a value which will be inserted into the `point` column (in case the data type is correct).